# parsing tab separated header of a file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, text-parsing

I'm trying to work out a generic script for getting the tab separated column values (as a header to the file). Separating via awk is fine for getting the column names. I'm not getting the idea as how to get each tab separated values until the end or the last NF(if using awk). The number of columns in the file isn't fix, sometime it might come up with 20 columns, sometime it could be 100, etc. 
For ex: the tab separated columns in the file are-

```
abc ttr nnc r32 inc ...
```

If I write a simple awk as:

```
head -1 file | awk 'BEGIN {NF="\t"} {print $1,$2, etc}
```

It'd present each tab separated column represented by $1, $2, etc. I tried an incremental version by replacing $1, $2, etc by $i but wouldn't work.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? did you try `awk 'BEGIN {NF="\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}`

Comment: Thanks for the response Avinash,
I already tried this and it's not giving the appropriate result. Some columns are space separated also like "Phone No.", in this case it shouldn't separate these two also cuz my NF is already "\t" but it's doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to loop over the fields from 1 to NF.  Here is an example of such a loop:

```
$ head -1 file | awk -F"\t" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i; print"";}'
abc ttr nnc r32 inc
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is what I wanted to. Guess I wasn't using printf correctly.

Comment: @habe you could do this with `tr '\t' ' '`. If you tell us what you're REALLY trying to do that makes you need to do this `tr`ansformation we could help...